# React Fluent UI - toast/tooltip when clicking on a button

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui

I have a button labeled like this

```
<Button icon={<CopyRegular />} onClick={() => doActionHere(parameters)}
```

When I click on the button, the action happens as expected, but I couldn't find in the Fluent UI documentation if there is a way to show like a message/toast under the button that shows the user that after clicking, something is happening.

Right now, when I click on the button, the action works as expected, but there is not sign to the user that they clicked on it, so it will be a poor user experience.

Is there any way to do that in Fluent UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to show a toast or tooltip when clicking on a button is to use the Toast component. This component takes a message prop that can be used to render a text message. The Toast component also takes an onHide prop that can be used to close the toast after a certain amount of time.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Toast } from '@fluentui/react';

const App = () => {
  const showToast = (message) => {
    // Show a toast
    const toast = new Toast({
      message,
      onHide: () => {
        console.log('Toast hidden');
      },
    });
    toast.show();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        icon={<CopyRegular />}
        onClick={() => showToast('Action completed')}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```